# How to decide Sharepoint URL field is set as Hyperlink or Picture?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How to decide Sharepoint URL field is set as Hyperlink or Picture?

I am having a List which has the URL field in it. Now I want to decide it  is Hyperlink or picture ?

Comment: Are you creating it or reading from it? both are `SPFieldURLValue` so you could access that property and then get the url and description from it.

Comment: I have a requirement where i have to make If else condition on Picture or URL type

Comment: if you have can you show me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the field as SPFieldUrl type. Then check its DisplayFormat property.

It will give you the result.

Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spurlfieldformattype.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587309(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587309%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {

                    SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];



                        SPFieldUrl field= new SPFieldUrl(list.Fields, "testUrl");
                        SPUrlFieldFormatType formatType = field.DisplayFormat;


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same type of field, if you want to use the URL and Descriptions programmatically you can do the following

```
var fieldName = "Web Page";
var url = ((SPListItem)user)[fieldName] != null ? (new SPFieldUrlValue(((SPListItem)user)[fieldName].ToString())).Url : string.Empty;
var desc = ((SPListItem)user)[fieldName] != null ? (new SPFieldUrlValue(((SPListItem)user)[fieldName].ToString())).Url : string.Empty;
```

you would do exactly the same for an image field.

Comment: I want to add if condition

Comment: Then you should use the information @Aanchal has listed above.